# I want the background to be black and text white on mouseover and background white and text black on mouse out

Tags: html, css, background-color

I've found this great tutorial http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/07/12/animated-text-and-icon-menu/

And I got stuck with something:

For example I want the background to be black and text white on mouseover and background white and text black on mouse out. How can I achieve this?

Because everytime I try to change the background colour on mouseover the text gets the background same colour on mouse out.

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: if you want to make using pure css use `:hover` with your settings

Comment: lol, seems like code request, by the way this question isn't about jquery.

Comment: This tutorial ignores equivalent keyboard events focus/blur :( (not everybody uses a mouse)

Comment: What have you tried? You got a jsfiddle of your attempts to share? What background? How does that relate to the link you provided?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<a class="my_link" href="#">Link</a>
```

CSS

```
.my_link {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

.my_link:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YXPFh/

Comment: I would also include `display:inline-block;` and add some padding if you want the link to look more like a button (and see the background color more).

Comment: Using LESS is even simpler ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='your-class'>content</div>
<style type="text/css">
.your-class {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
.your-class:hover {
 /* new rules */
}
</style>
```